Monster movie with college kids in castle
I recall seeing a monster movie late one night many years ago. Specifics are lacking. I believe it was a group of coeds visiting a family castle. I can't recall what type of monster (perhaps vampire or werewolf). It turned out the monster was one of the kids. I believe it was hereditary, and the monster might not have been aware they were a monster. I think the monster "wins." I also think it was early 90s, but it might have been late 80s.
I really hope someone can help.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

It could be The Club (1994) 

Time stops at midnight at the Senior Prom for five students, one murderous counselor, and John. They must find the courage to face themselves or, when time starts again, they may find that they are joining John's Club. All you have to do is commit murder... or suicide.




